# HTML checkboxes

Tags: html, checkbox

I have two checkboxes (unchecked) one page and I want this:
when one of this checkbox will be check the second one will be also check and conversely when one of this (now already checked) will be check off the second one will be also check off.

Comment: that is what you want, alright. But what is the problem? How did you try to solve it? We need a little more input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery for this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
       $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','checked') ;
      
       
    }else{
          $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked','') ;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have inputs like this:

```
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoth()">Checkbox One</input>
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" onclick="checkBoth()">Checkbox Two</input>
```

Then you just need simple javascript function like this:

```
function checkBoth() {
    document.getElementById('c1').checked = true;
    document.getElementById('c2').checked = true;
}
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oc0x90Le/1/)